# Apex trigger lacks test coverage, but I have a test class

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

We had an offshore team develop us an app, they have installed it in my developer account and now I am trying to make a package for app exchange submission.

I select the app, the apex classes including test classes and the trigger (app only has 1 trigger) and when I attempt to upload the package I get this message back

> > One or more Apex triggers lack test coverage. Add test coverage for the following triggers and upload again: LeadSurveyDeleteEvent

Here is the LeadSurveyDeleteEvent trigger

```
trigger LeadSurveyDeleteEvent on Lead (before delete) 
{
    Map<ID,Lead> old_lead_list = Trigger.oldMap;
    Set<ID> ids = old_lead_List.keySet();
    delete [Select ID from Survey__c where SurveyLead__c IN :ids];
}
```

And the test class

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class LeadSurveyDeleteEventTest {

    static testMethod void addDeleteLeadTest()
    {
        String [] arrayOfId = new List<String>();
        arrayOfId.Add('12');
        arrayOfId.Add('13');
        delete [Select ID from Survey__c where SurveyLead__c IN :arrayOfId];    
    }
}
```

I am not familiar with Apex code but when I run the test it completes 1/1.

Edit: After your comments on the quality of code I updated it myself:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class LeadSurveyDeleteEventTest {

    static testMethod void testLeadTrigger_Delete()
    {

        Lead newLead = new Lead();
        newLead.Email = 'test@test.com';
        newLead.Company = 'Test Company Name';
        newLead.LastName = 'Smith';
        insert newLead;

        Survey_Responses__c newSurveyResponse = new Survey_Responses__c();
        newSurveyResponse.Survey_Name__c = 'Test survey name1';
        newSurveyResponse.Question__c = 'Where do you live?';
        newSurveyResponse.Answer__c = 'Canada';
        newSurveyResponse.SurveyLead__c = newLead.Id;
        insert newSurveyResponse;

        Test.startTest();
        delete newLead;
        Test.stopTest();

        Lead tLead = [Select Id, IsDeleted from Lead WHERE Id = :newLead.Id ALL ROWS];
        System.assertEquals(tLead.IsDeleted, true);

        Survey_Responses__c tSurveyResponse = [Select Id, IsDeleted from Survey_Responses__c WHERE Id = :newSurveyResponse.Id ALL ROWS];
        System.assertEquals(tSurveyResponse.IsDeleted, true);   
}
```

}

Can someone shed light on what the ALL ROWS words do? And the startTest/endTest block?

Comment: From the quality of the code you posted, Suggest next time not to use that development team. Basic fundamentals are incorrect here...Adrian has hit the sweet spot on your answer...

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will be sure to pass it on to my boss. I will have to study up on Apex test cases and review them all.

Comment: it's not just the test case that's low quality, it's the trigger itself as well. Never a better time to start learning.

Comment: @andrew Please do not edit your post to reflect an ***entirely different question***. Instead, if your original question is resolved, accept the answer that helped you most and ask a *new question* in a *separate post*.

Answer (score 2):

To test a trigger on `Lead`, you need to operate on the `Lead` object. In this case, you will need to delete one or (preferably) more records.

```
static testmethod void testLeadTrigger_Delete
{
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
    // add records;
    insert leads;

    // create child Survey__c records

    Test.startTest();
        delete leads;
    Test.stopTest();

    // assert the child records got deleted as well
}
```

Also note that your trigger has a few lines which are completely unnecessary:

```
Map<ID,Lead> old_lead_list = Trigger.oldMap;
Set<ID> ids = old_lead_List.keySet();
```

These lines don't really add anything as you can just merge the keyset directly into your query:

```
WHERE SurveyLead__c IN :trigger.oldMap.keySet()
```